# Calculating bamboo index

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, ndvi

I am working on my project on bamboo distribution using RS. As per the literature, I found that bamboo indices is calculated as: BI = (NDVI-SI)/(NDVI+SI); Where NDVI is vegetation index and SI as soil moisture index. NDVI for Landsat-8 was calculated as: - NDVI = (Band5-Band4)/(Band5+Band4) and SI as = (Band5-Band6)/(Band5+Band6). The NDVI and SI map was rendered. Now, to calculate BI; the following expression was used:-

[image]
Note: SIB6 above is Soil Index Value calculated as:- SIB6 = (NIR (Band 5)-SWIR6 (Band 6))/(Band 5+Band6).

Now, though the map is produced;but it look like this:

[[image]]

But the map rendered doesn't seem truly representing the Bamboo Indices map. Is it because of the expression above or what???

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: @Hornbydd But using the above expression, BI indices value was only obtained as -1 and 1 rather than series of value like NDVI. Why is this happening?

Comment: You did not say that in your question, you asked if the expression was correct and from the information you are displaying I would say yes it is correct.

Comment: Without further information, such as format of rasters, version of ArcMap, all anyone could suggest is try enclosing your rasters in Float(), so something like `(Float("r2.tif") - Float("r1.tif")) / (Float("r2.tif") + Float("r1.tif"))`.

Comment: @Hornbydd; If Bamboo Index (BI)= (NDVI-NDMI )/(NDVI-NDMI) ; NDVI = (Band 5 - Band 4) / (Band 5 + Band 4) and NDMI = (Band 5 - Band 6) / (Band 5 + Band 6) then;  does the expression needs to be:- [(Band 5 - Band 4) * (Band 5 + Band 6) - (Band 5 - Band 6) * (Band 5 + Band 4)] / [(Band 5 - Band 4) * (Band 5 + Band 6) + (Band 5 - Band 6) * (Band 5 + Band 4)]  ??? But when I used this expression using raster calculator the map wasn't rendered.

Comment: You could exploded it out into the individual bands as you have done, but that approach becomes unreadable to others. I would calculate the two indices separately (the NDVI and SI) then use those to calculate your bamboo index. But why are you now multiplying bands? Nowhere in your question do you talk about multiplying bands...

Comment: @Hornbydd ; I tried using the expression as suggested by you as shown in image above. But the map is not properly rendered as shown in question.

Comment: Out of interest, if you use the info tool and click randomly in your bamboo raster, does it in fact return sensible values or are they all constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a few extreme values are skewing your symbology, making it hard to tell if your index is working as expected.

It sounds like you've already double checked your equation, which would be the first thing to check. I recommend following @Hornbydd's advice in the comments of calculating NDVI and SI separately, then using those in the Bamboo Index equation, as this will improve readability of your process.

The next step is to adjust your symbology - try making some manual categories that separate out the outliers into one or two buckets, and then focus most of the color change on the values you expect. That highlight if there's a problem with the equation, or a handful of outliers that might warrant further investigation.